# Object not found in function R

Tags: r, function, object, missing-data

I have a function as follows:

```
rLoadRun = function(pFile, fFile, varName, flowName, dateName, stationName){
   rRun = selBestModel(varName, data=pFile, flow="Q", flow.units="cms",
                dates="Date", station="Holt station", time.step="day")
   concentration = predConc(rRun, fFile, by="day")
   return(concentration)
}
```

`selBestModel` and `predConc` both come from the rloadest package by USGS, but they are a bit irrelevant for the problem. I created a test call:

```
test = rLoadRun(file, file2, "Q", "Q", "Date", "Test")
print(test)
```

and I receive the error:

> Error in terms.formula(formula, "model", data = data) :    object
>   'pFile' not found

Maybe this is an issue with my understanding of R, but I thought since the function defined pFile as a variable to be passed in, it would exist in the scope of the function. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.  What is `file` and `file2`?

Comment: `file` already is the name of a function, in `connections {base}`.

Comment: I could change the name of file and file2 to something else -- say example and example2. This exact code is what I'm running to receive the error, so it seems reproducible to me?

Comment: What is the output of `ls()`? Do the objects `file` and `file2` exist in your workspace?

Comment: This is a step in a bigger program, so my ls() has a LOT of entries -- But by sending in objects from ls() I still receive the same error. In the case where this first came up, I'm sending in two dataframes holtChem and subChemH.

Comment: Ok, if `ls()` returns a long vector, you can `grep("file", ls())`. If you call `rloadest::selBestModel` directly, outside function `rLoadRun` do you still get the same error?

Comment: Oh neat! That's a great trick. If I call rloadest directly, I do NOT get the same error, it runs fine. Currently how I'm gimping my code along.